# How to add 1 to the value of a column of an existing row in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table called pollData. It will always contain only 1 row. It has columns option1, option2, option3, option4, option5 each of type int. In the beginning, these columns have 0 as their value. How do I add 1 to any column, say option2? I mean do i retrieve the value of that column first, perform addition, and store back, or is there any auto increment function?

Comment: Are you worked on my result solution? It is in answer part.

Comment: No. Didnt try it out. astander's solution seemed perfect. Also, I don't think it will work since all my options are already set to 0 in the beginning. isset(..) will always return true.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could try a normal [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), and just replace the column option in question.

```
UPDATE pollData SET option2 = option2 + 1
```

Comment: Inside of a transaction, sure. Not naked by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Like this you can try :

```
if(isset($option1)) {
       $optadd = " option1 = option1+1";
    } else if(isset($option2)) {
       $optadd = " option2 = option2+1";
    }

UPDATE `tablename` SET ".$optadd." WHERE fieldname = '1'
```